# How can we say that 'adverbs are placed as close as possible to the words they are supposed to modify'

Tags: adverbs, adverbials

eg. **He ate the cake quickly**, In this sentence 'quickly' modifies 'ate' but they are not close to each other.

Comment: Can you give us the source of this statement? As it stands it is useless and misleading as a guide to the placement of adverbs.

Comment: @Shoe https://www.grammarly.com/blog/adverb/ 'placement of adverb'

Comment: Thanks. After the sentence you cite in your question, Grammarly says: _When an adverb is modifying a verb phrase, the most natural place for the adverb is usually the middle of the phrase._ If Grammarly replaces _the most natural place_ with _the typical place_, then we have a more useful statement. But _quickly_ can also start or end the example sentence, depending on what the writer wants to emphasise.

Comment: The words are close.  They are not next to each other, but the problem with distant adverbs tends to be more, "He ate the cake, which was chocolate with strawberry frosting and chocolate chips, and made by his favorite bakery, down the street, quickly." where you can't easily tell which word the adverb modifies.

Comment: It is close. "Quickly" modifies the VP "ate the cake". It's fine where you have it, and it's equally fine in front position too, as in "We quickly ate the cake". But it's not OK in the middle, as *"We ate quickly the cake" because adverbs should not separate a verb and its object.

Comment: @BillJ If object is long, then adverb separate verb and it's object

Comment: @ketanpendharkar But "the cake" is not long, so *"ate quickly the cake" is unacceptable. I think you have your answer.

Comment: _As a rule of thumb, though with many exceptions and much flexibility, adverbs are placed as close as possible to the words they modify._

Comment: @BillJ eg. He can park your car here, In this sentence here(adverb) modifies phrase 'can park your car' , am I right?

Comment: It modifies the VP "park your car".

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Can you explain more, please?

Comment: @BillJ https://www.grammarly.com/blog/adverb/ 'placement of adverb' section: There is a sentence 'Phillip fed only the cat' in this sentence only(adverb) is place between verb and its object also here object is small, why?

Comment: @ketanpendharkar "Only" is not between the verb and its object. It modifies the object ("the cat") and is thus part of the object. This is different to "quickly", which is a modifier in the VP, not the NP object.

Comment: @BillJ Thank you

Comment: On ELU, look up 'placement of adverbs' and 'placement of only' to see  non-exhaustive overviews and an analysis of the distribution of the focus particle _only_ respectively. // With your sentence, initial (Quickly, he ate the cake), pre-verb medial (He quickly ate the cake) and terminal (He ate the cake quickly) are available; identicle in meaning, with different emphases.

Answer (score -1):

The adverb is close in that sentence.  It is not immediately after, but in warnings against putting adverbs far from the word that they modify, the intent is to warn against lack of clarity, because the adverb can not be connected to the proper word by the reader.

Far means something more like

> He ate the cake, which was chocolate with strawberry frosting and chocolate chips rather than the usual vanilla frosting with candy hearts, because it was made by his favorite bakery, down the street, quickly.

Comment: Yes, but "quickly" modifies the VP "ate the cake", so the adverb is in fact immediately adjacent to the item it modifies.

Comment: No, the verbal phrase is in fact "ate the cake quickly", consisting of the verb, its object, and the adverb that modifies it.

Comment: What?  Of course that's the full VP; that's obvious. But when we show the phrase that is being modified, we show it without its modifier. As I said, the adverb is immediately adjacent to the phrase it modifies.

Comment: No, "quickly" is not modifying the verbal phrase.  We can tell by the way that by your logic, the sentence I have is putting the adverb next to the verbal phrase and is therefore equally correct.

Comment: The VP in full is "ate the cake quickly", with "ate" as predicator, "the cake" as Od, and "quickly" as adjunct.